# iOS: formatting decimal numbers

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an `NSDecimalNumber` representing a money amount.
I want to print it as "999 999 999 999 999 999,00", regardless on the locale.
How do I do that?

NSNumberFormatter prints me 1 000 000 000 000 000 000,00 instead (it seems Apple engineers never designed the iPhone to be a platform for financial software).

`[NSDecimalNumber description]` and `[NSDecimalNumber descriptionWithLocale]` both print correct value. How can I format the result, with grouping separator set to `@"\u2006"`, decimal separator to `@"**,**"`, and exactly 2 decimal digits after the decimal seperator?

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**
Here's my solution, 10x to Sulthan:

```
@implementation NSDecimalNumber(MiscUtils)

-(NSString*)moneyToString
{
    static NSDecimalNumberHandler* s_handler = nil;
    if( !s_handler )
        s_handler = [ [ NSDecimalNumberHandler decimalNumberHandlerWithRoundingMode:NSRoundPlain scale:2 raiseOnExactness:NO raiseOnOverflow:NO raiseOnUnderflow:NO raiseOnDivideByZero:NO ] retain ];

    NSDecimalNumber *dec = [ self decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior:s_handler ];
    NSString* str = [ dec description ];
    NSRange rDot = [ str rangeOfString:@"." ];
    int nIntDigits = str.length;
    int nFracDigits = 0;
    if( rDot.length > 0 )
    {
        nIntDigits = rDot.location;
        nFracDigits = str.length - ( rDot.location + 1 );
    }
    int nGroupSeparators = ( nIntDigits - 1 ) / 3;

    NSMutableString* res = [ NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:nIntDigits + nGroupSeparators + 3 ];
    NSString *groupingSeparator = @"\u2006";

    int nFirstGroup = ( nIntDigits % 3 );
    int nextInd = 0;
    if( nFirstGroup )
    {
        [ res appendString:[ str substringToIndex:nFirstGroup ] ];
        nextInd = nFirstGroup;
    }

    while( nextInd < nIntDigits )
    {
        if( res.length > 0 )
            [ res appendString:groupingSeparator ];
        [ res appendString:[ str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange( nextInd, 3 ) ] ];
        nextInd += 3;
    }

    if( nFracDigits > 0 )
    {
        if( nFracDigits > 2 )
            nFracDigits = 2;
        [ res appendString:@"," ];
        [ res appendString:[ str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange( rDot.location + 1, nFracDigits ) ] ];
        while( nFracDigits < 2 )
        {
            [ res appendString:@"0" ];
            nFracDigits++;
        }
    }
    else
        [ res appendString:@",00" ];
//  DLog( "formatDecimal: %@ -> %@", dec, res );
    return res;
}
@end
```

Comment: Why would you want to force the use of a comma in locales that use a point for decimals?

Comment: @Marcelo, the customer insists on that. Anyway, I already managed to supply NSDictionary with NSLocaleDecimalSeparator key to descriptionWithLocale overriding the decimal separator. The two remaining questions are grouping separator, and number of decimal digits..

Comment: I understand the customer is asking for a fixed format, but they really might want to respect the user's local instead. See the "Getting Your Apps Ready for China and other Hot New Markets" WWDC session for more information <https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=131>

Comment: I agree with the other guys how it should be the programmers have to do what the customer wants. However, the actual issue is that `NSNumberFormatter`does not format `NSDecimalNumber` correctly and it decreases the precision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. I was told that `NSNumberFormatter` converts everything to a `double` first. How did I solve it? It's easy, just write your own formatter.

1. First round the decimal to 2 decimal digits.
2. Get its description as a string.
3. Find decimal point (.) in the string and replace it with the one you want.
4. After every three digits from the decimal point to the left, insert a grouping separator.

Comment: 10x, it worked.However, I would prefer this functionality to be in the framework - .NET has it for years..

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
    NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"US"];

    NSNumberFormatter *frm = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [frm setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    [frm setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
    [frm setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
    [frm setLocale:usLocale];
    NSString *formattedNumberStr = [frm stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:floatToRound]];

    [frm release];
[usLocale release];

    return formattedNumberStr;
```

Comment: You should never store a money amount in a binary floating point data type.
This code prints incorrect value.

Comment: You can pick a properly location to get a right format that you are expecting, yes, you are right, you should use double instead, but you question is format float number.