# NSNumberFormatter iOS big double value

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a problem formatting big numbers.

I first format a string to a number and since i need to save a string, i get the stringValue from it:

```
formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setUsesSignificantDigits:NO];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:6];
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
[formatter setGroupingSeparator:@""];
value = [formatter numberFromString:textField.text];
label = [value stringValue]
```

and everything is ok, i.e. if i enter 123456745678592.6, i'll get 123456745678592.6.

Then i've to format the string because of different locale:

```
numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[numberFormatter setGroupingSeparator:@""];
[numberFormatter setUsesSignificantDigits:NO];
[numberFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:6];
tempString = myNumberString;
NSLog(@"number: %@",[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[tempString doubleValue]]);
tempString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[tempString doubleValue]]];
NSLog(@"string translated: %@",tempString);
```

and i get this:
"number: 123456745678592.6"
"string translated: 123456745678593"

This rounding happens when the significative digits are greater than 15.

Let's say i enter:
12345674567859.2
i then get the right number, i.e.
"number: 12345674567859.2"
"string translated: 12345674567859.2"

with:
12345674567859.23
i get:
"number: 12345674567859.23"
"string translated: 12345674567859.2"

but with:
1234567456785921
i get this:
"number: 1234567456785921"
"string translated: 1234567456785920"

Is this an intrinsic limit of the nsnumberformatter, because the documentation says nothing about this, or i'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Could you check what is the actual class of the number? Is it `NSNumber` or `NSDecimalNumber`?

A `NSNumber` is backed up by a `double` and cannot hold more than 15 significant decimal digits. On the other hand, `NSDecimalNumber` uses decimal arithmetics and can hold up to 32 significant digits.

I have already learned that `NSDecimalFormatter` cannot format `NSDecimalNumber`s correctly (see [iOS: formatting decimal numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385783/ios-formatting-decimal-numbers/9385920#9385920)).
But maybe it can create a `NSDecimalNumber` correctly from a string.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not in the limit of the NSNumberFormatter, it´s in the limit of the double itself.

The max value of a double in Objective-C is 15 digits, I think that is a good clue about what is going on in your program.

I think that when you are doing this¨

```
[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[tempString doubleValue]]];
```

You are limiting the value of the NSNumber, because doubleValue is going to have a limit!

Comment: I thought about this but, as you can see in my post, NSLog(@"number: %@",[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[tempString doubleValue]]); prints the correct value without any truncation. It begins to truncate when the digits are greater than 16.

Comment: Have u tried using [numberFormatter setMaxium: ] then? You can also access to the maximum and read the value of it

Comment: Have u checked the maximum value?