# How to test NSDecimalNumber with an NSLocale that produces commas in number

Tags: ios, internationalization

I'm trying to support customers whose native language uses commas rather than decimal points, and I created a method that I think should work, but I have not been able to set an NSLocale to produce commas in the value. Here is the method:

```
-(NSString *)localNumber:(double)d decimals:(int)n{

    NSLocale *deLoc = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"fr"];

    NSDecimalNumber *dn = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%4.*f", n, d]];
    NSString *dnS = [dn descriptionWithLocale:deLoc];

    return dnS;
}
```

But the output is always like:

1.67

Comment: the call that produces 1.67 is:

[self localNumber:1.66666 decimals:2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that descriptionWithLocale has a bug and it isn't working correctly.  I verified that the decimal seperator for the "fr" locale is indeed a comma, but it is using the period.

Anyway, here is a way to do it:

```
-(NSString *)localNumber:(double)d decimals:(int)n{
    NSDecimalNumber *dn = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%4.*f", n, d]];

    NSLocale *deLoc = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"fr"];
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setLocale:deLoc];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    NSString *dnS = [formatter stringFromNumber:dn];

    return dnS;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is gonna work with `NSDecimalNumber`? See question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385783/ios-formatting-decimal-numbers/9385920#9385920.

Comment: I just tested it and it worked fine.  :)  The problem in the question that you linked to is about rounding of values that double's don't have the precision to represent.  And, of course, he is starting with a double anyway so precision won't be an issue with this routine.

Comment: Infziger - you are right. I am only warning everybody when I see `NSDecimalNumber` used with `NSNumberFormatter` :)